# Getting stripe across tiles without buffering image?

Tags: geotools, imagery, pixel

I am new to geotools.  I need to get a horizontal stripe of bytes from the image data without buffering the whole image.  I've looked at the various envelopes and pretty sure I could use just Rectangle2D since I don't need the coordinaterefsystem.  But for the life of me I can't figure out how to use the rectangle/envelope without doing:

```
GridCoverage2DReader gridReader = format.getReader(this.getInputFile(), hints);
GridCoverage2D gridCoverage = gridReader.read(null);
```

I don't see a replacement in JAI-EXT for ImageReadDescriptor.

For those wondering why, legacy code appears to have a memory leak. Below is the code where I see avail memory drop with each loop.  I used Thread.sleep(x) so I could watch it in top.  This is not a heap issue, the machine core dumps with an out of memory error and an exit code of 137.  Java mission control shows the heap is cleaned nicely.

```
RenderedImage img = ImageReadDescriptor.create(ImageInputStream iis, ...);
... //calculate stripeSize

byte[] writeBuff = new byte[stripeSize*numLines];
for(nCalculatedChunksOfLines){
  Rectangle tb = new Rectangle(0, n, sample, linesInChunk );
  Raster stripe = img.getData(tb);

  ...rest of processing bypassed for debugging....
  if(stripe != null){
    continue;
  }
}
```

I would rather replace the legacy code but if there are no simple options then a suggested fix to the legacy code would be helpful.  I'm going to test closing and opening the stream for each rectangle retrieve.